# Suppose $X$ and $Y$ have joint density $f(x,y)=1$ for $0<x,y<1$. Find $P(XY\leq z)$

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

So far I have $$P(XY\leq z)=\int_?^?\int_0^{z/y}1dxdy$$ but I am unsure how to find the bounds or how to actually set this up.

Comment: Draw a picture. First draw the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ in the $(x,y)$-plane, and then sketch the area $\{(x,y): xy>z\}$. Note that I've turned the inequality around: you will see why when you sketch the region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want $\big(0<x\leq 1\big), \big(0<y\leq 1\big), \big(0< xy\leq z\big)$ to all be true.

Which is $\big(0<y\leq 1\big)$ and $\big(0<x\leq \min\{1, z/y\}\big)$ for any $z:\big(0<z\leq 1\big)$

$$\begin{align}\mathbf P(XY\leq z) & = \mathbf 1_{0< z\leq 1} \int_0^{1} \int_0^{\min\{1, z/y\}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y + \mathbf 1_{z>1}
\\[1ex] & =
\mathbf 1_{0< z\leq 1} \left(\int_{?}^{?} \int_0^1 f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y + \int_{?}^{?} \int_0^{z/y} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\operatorname d x\operatorname d y\right) + \mathbf 1_{z>1}
\end{align}$$

Now just work out how to split the outer integral into two domains where the inner integral does not contain a minimum function.

That is: what values of y in $(0;1)$ is $1<z/y$, and where is it that $1\geq z/y$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $-\log X-\log Y$ is a sum of two i.i.d. exponentials - i.e. Erlang with shape parameter $2$. Hence

$P(XY\le z)=P(-\log X-\log Y \ge -\log z)=P(Erl(2,1)\ge -\log z)=z(1+\log \frac 1 z)$.